# how to convert al the image data into array

Tags: python

```
folder = r'C:\Users\jabed\Desktop\mask and not mask\train\with mask'

onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f))]

print("Working with {0} images".format(len(onlyfiles)))
```

Comment: what's the error you are receiving? see [ask] a question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os` module to list all the files in the directory:

```
import os

path = "C:\\someLocation"
onlyfiles = os.listdir(path)
```

Comment: i want to convert all the directory image to array ..

Comment: You can loop through all the files and check if they contain an image file extension like `.png`, `.jpg`, etc.